# List-style-image not working: no markers present

Tags: css, list, html-lists, markers

Here is my CSS:

```
#navcontainerF ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: url('img/sqpurple.gif');
text-align: center;
border-style:solid;
border-top:thin dashed #D2BDBE;
border-left:thin dashed #D2BDBE;
border-right:thin dashed #D2BDBE;
border-bottom:thin dashed #D2BDBE;
}

#navcontainerF ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainerF ul li a
{   
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: .2em 1em;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainerF">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.php">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="page4.php">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I expect to see a bullet point list with **markers** but no such markers appear.
I definitely have the correct image url for "list-style-image".
What might be the problem?

Thanks very much,
Harry

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image path is relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file. So if you have your stylesheet in a folder called CSS, then you would have to put:

```
list-style-image: url('../img/sqpurple.gif');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a left padding in order to give them some space

```
#navcontainerF ul {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Or place them inside:

```
#navcontainerF ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I've tried both of these and there is still no appearance of markers.

Comment: The padding does what you'd expect it to do, but the markers still aren't present.   Would a fiddle help?

Comment: @THarryEvans Yes, please provide a fiddle, since I think it should work.